# How to bin in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

For example, I'd like to classify a `DataFrame` of people into the following 4 bins according to age.

```
age_bins = [0, 6, 18, 60, np.Inf]
age_labels = ['infant', 'minor', 'adult', 'senior']
```

I would use `pandas.cut()` to do this in `pandas`. How do I do this in `PySpark`?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use Bucketizer feature transfrom from ml library in spark.

```
values = [("a", 23), ("b", 45), ("c", 10), ("d", 60), ("e", 56), ("f", 2), ("g", 25), ("h", 40), ("j", 33)]


df = spark.createDataFrame(values, ["name", "ages"])


from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer
bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=[ 0, 6, 18, 60, float('Inf') ],inputCol="ages", outputCol="buckets")
df_buck = bucketizer.setHandleInvalid("keep").transform(df)

df_buck.show()
```

output

```
+----+----+-------+
|name|ages|buckets|
+----+----+-------+
|   a|  23|    2.0|
|   b|  45|    2.0|
|   c|  10|    1.0|
|   d|  60|    3.0|
|   e|  56|    2.0|
|   f|   2|    0.0|
|   g|  25|    2.0|
|   h|  40|    2.0|
|   j|  33|    2.0|
+----+----+-------+
```

If you want names for each bucket you can use udf to create a new column with bucket names

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

t = {0.0:"infant", 1.0: "minor", 2.0:"adult", 3.0: "senior"}
udf_foo = udf(lambda x: t[x], StringType())
df_buck.withColumn("age_bucket", udf_foo("buckets")).show()
```

output

```
+----+----+-------+----------+
|name|ages|buckets|age_bucket|
+----+----+-------+----------+
|   a|  23|    2.0|     adult|
|   b|  45|    2.0|     adult|
|   c|  10|    1.0|     minor|
|   d|  60|    3.0|    senior|
|   e|  56|    2.0|     adult|
|   f|   2|    0.0|    infant|
|   g|  25|    2.0|     adult|
|   h|  40|    2.0|     adult|
|   j|  33|    2.0|     adult|
+----+----+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 9):

You could also write a PySpark UDF:

```
def categorizer(age):
  if age < 6:
    return "infant"
  elif age < 18:
    return "minor"
  elif age < 60:
    return "adult"
  else: 
    return "senior"
```

Then:

```
bucket_udf = udf(categorizer, StringType() )
bucketed = df.withColumn("bucket", bucket_udf("age"))
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to randomly bucket a **string value column**, so it required me some extra steps:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType, IntegerType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


buckets_number = 4    # number of buckets desired

df.withColumn("sub", F.substring(F.md5('my_col'), 0, 16)) \
  .withColumn("translate", F.translate("sub", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "01234567890123456789012345").cast(LongType())) \
  .select("my_col",
         (F.col("translate") % (buckets_number + 1)).cast(IntegerType()).alias("bucket_my_col"))
```

1. hash it with MD5
2. substring the result to 16 characters (otherwise would have a too big number in following steps)
3. translate letters generated by MD5 in numbers
4. apply modulo function based on the number of desired buckets

Answer (score 1):

In case you know the **bin width**, then you can use division with a cast. The result is multiplied by the bin width to get the lower bound of the bin as a label.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

def categorize(df, bin_width):
    df = df.withColumn('bucket', (col('value') / bin_width).cast(IntegerType()) * bin_width)
    return df 

values = [("a", 23), ("b", 45), ("e", 56), ("f", 2)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(values, ["name", "value"])
categorize(df, bin_width=10).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+---+------+
|name|age|bucket|
+----+---+------+
|   a| 23|    20|
|   b| 45|    40|
|   e| 56|    50|
|   f|  2|     0|
+----+---+------+
```

Notice that it also works for **floating point attributes**:

```
values = [("a", .23), ("b", .45), ("e", .56), ("f", .02)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(values, ["name", "value"])
categorize(df, bin_width=.10).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-----+------+
|name|value|bucket|
+----+-----+------+
|   a| 0.23|   0.2|
|   b| 0.45|   0.4|
|   e| 0.56|   0.5|
|   f| 0.02|   0.0|
+----+-----+------+
```