# Spark SQL group data by range and trigger alerts

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am processing the data stream from Kafka using structured streaming with pyspark. I want to publish alerts to Kafka if the readings are abnormal in avro format

```
source  temperature timestamp
1001    21  4/28/2019 10:25
1001    22  4/28/2019 10:26
1001    23  4/28/2019 10:27
1001    24  4/28/2019 10:28
1001    25  4/28/2019 10:29
1001    34  4/28/2019 10:30
1001    37  4/28/2019 10:31
1001    36  4/28/2019 10:32
1001    38  4/28/2019 10:33
1001    40  4/28/2019 10:34
1001    41  4/28/2019 10:35
1001    42  4/28/2019 10:36
1001    45  4/28/2019 10:37
1001    47  4/28/2019 10:38
1001    50  4/28/2019 10:39
1001    41  4/28/2019 10:40
1001    42  4/28/2019 10:41
1001    45  4/28/2019 10:42
1001    47  4/28/2019 10:43
1001    50  4/28/2019 10:44

Transform 
source  range   count   alert
1001    21-25   5   HIGH
1001    26-30   5   MEDIUM
1001    40-45   5   MEDIUM
1001    45-50   5   HIGH
```

I have defined a window function with 20 sec and 1 sec sliding. I am able to publish alerts with simple where condition but I am not able to tranform the data frame like above and trigger alerts if the count is 20 for any alert priority (all records in a window are matches with any priority HIGH->count(20) etc). Can any one suggest how to do this?

Also I am able to publish data using json format but not able to generate using AVRO. Scala and Java has to_avro() function but pyspark doesn't have any.

Appreciate your response

Comment: Please share code example as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this problem using Bucketizer feature transfrom from ml library in spark.

[How to bin in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225587/how-to-bin-in-pyspark)