# Make Bins in pyspark with range of values and specific values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, categories, categorization

I want to make bins on a pyspark dataframe column with range of values and specific values

In this post [How to bin in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225587/how-to-bin-in-pyspark) It explains how yo make the bins, but it is only for range of values, from 0 to 6, from 6 to 18, and so on, I would like to have just a bin for specific values, for example, I want bins from 0 to 5, 5 to 9, 10, 11 to 20, 21 and more

```
+-----------+
| Age | Bin |
+-----------+
|  4  |  1  |
| 10  |  3  |
|  6  |  2  |
| 40  |  5  |
|  2  |  1  |
|  8  |  2  |
+-----------+
```

I tried

```
splits = [ 0, 5, 9, 10, 10, 11, float('Inf') ]
```

But It gives an error

I used a tolerance to make the bin just for 10, but I am wondering if there is a better way

```
tol= 1.0e-10
splits = [ 0, 5, 9, 10, 10+tol, 11, float('Inf') ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can manually specify a `CASE WHEN` column for binning:

```py
from functools import reduce

splits = [ 0, 5, 9, 10, 11 ]
splits = list(enumerate(splits))
# >>> splits
# [(0, 0), (1, 5), (2, 9), (3, 10), (4, 11)]

bins = reduce(lambda c, i: c.when(F.col('Age') <= i[1], i[0]), splits, F.when(F.col('Age') < splits[0][0], None)).otherwise(splits[-1][0] + 1).alias('bins')
# >>> bins
# Column<b'CASE WHEN (Age < 0) THEN NULL WHEN (Age <= 0) THEN 0 WHEN (Age <= 5) THEN 1 WHEN (Age <= 9) THEN 2 WHEN (Age <= 10) THEN 3 WHEN (Age <= 11) THEN 4 ELSE 5 END AS `bins`'>

df = df.select('age', bins)

df.show()
+---+----+
|age|bins|
+---+----+
|  4|   1|
| 10|   3|
|  6|   2|
| 40|   5|
|  2|   1|
|  8|   2|
+---+----+
```